# Connect 2 Memcached servers on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, memcached

I want to  have separated  Memcached   one for session and another for cache

I tried to do this  in  Config/cache.php

```
'memcached' => [
    'driver' => 'memcached',
    'persistent_id' => env('MEMCACHED_PERSISTENT_ID'),
    'sasl' => [
        env('MEMCACHED_USERNAME'),
        env('MEMCACHED_PASSWORD'),
    ],
    'options' => [
        // Memcached::OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT => 2000,
    ],
    'servers' => [
        [
            'host' => env('MEMCACHED_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('MEMCACHED_PORT', 11211),
            'weight' => 100,
        ],
    ],
],

'memcachedz2' => [
    'driver' => 'memcached',
    'persistent_id' => env('MEMCACHED_PERSISTENT_ID'),
    'sasl' => [
        env('MEMCACHED_USERNAME'),
        env('MEMCACHED_PASSWORD'),
    ],
    'options' => [
        // Memcached::OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT => 2000,
    ],
    'servers' => [
        [
            'host' => env('MEMCACHED_HOST1', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('MEMCACHED_PORT1', 11211),
            'weight' => 100,
        ],
    ],
],
```

and in .env file  I added

```
CACHE_DRIVER=memcached
CACHE_PREFIX=areviwez_cache
SESSION_DRIVER=memcachedz2

MEMCACHED_HOST=35.192.75.119
MEMCACHED_PORT=11211


MEMCACHED_HOST1=127.0.0.1
MEMCACHED_PORT1=11211
```

I'm getting this error

```
Driver [memcachedz2] not supported
```

but it didn't work
Is it possible to make it work like this ?

Comment: There's an extra z in `memcachedz2`

Comment: I was trying to change the names, so I copied the wrong text

Comment: I don't think you can use a custom cache driver for the session. In your case the easiest approach is to define `memcached` to use your 2nd connection and use `memcachedz2` as your default cache driver. Otherwise you'd need to add a [custom session driver](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/session#adding-custom-session-drivers) for memcachedz2. You can use the already included `CacheBasedSessionHandler` using the custom cache configuration for this purpose

Comment: @apokryfos   thank it worked as you explained I just switched them    please add your answer, so I can accept it  as it might help others

Comment: Why don't you put both servers (addresses and ports) into `servers` array?

Comment: @MarkusZeller if I do that, how can I determine  which one will be used for session and the other for cache  can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session driver that is specified in `config/session.php` is not related to the cache driver configuration therefore `memcached` (meaning use the memcached session driver) would be supported but `memcachedz2` would not be supported in your case because there's no session driver defined as `memcachedz2` (only a cache driver).

You have 2 options:

1. Flip your cache driver configurations:

```
'memcached' => [
    'driver' => 'memcached',
    'persistent_id' => env('MEMCACHED_PERSISTENT_ID'),
    'sasl' => [
        env('MEMCACHED_USERNAME'),
        env('MEMCACHED_PASSWORD'),
    ],
    'options' => [
        // Memcached::OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT => 2000,
    ],
    'servers' => [
        [
            'host' => env('MEMCACHED_HOST1', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('MEMCACHED_PORT1', 11211),
            'weight' => 100,
        ],
    ],
],

'memcachedz2' => [
    'driver' => 'memcached',
    'persistent_id' => env('MEMCACHED_PERSISTENT_ID'),
    'sasl' => [
        env('MEMCACHED_USERNAME'),
        env('MEMCACHED_PASSWORD'),
    ],
    'options' => [
        // Memcached::OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT => 2000,
    ],
    'servers' => [
        [
            'host' => env('MEMCACHED_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('MEMCACHED_PORT', 11211),
            'weight' => 100,
        ],
    ],
],
```

and in your .env file:

```
CACHE_DRIVER=memcachedz2
CACHE_PREFIX=areviwez_cache
SESSION_DRIVER=memcached
```

2. Define a cache driver for `memcachedz2` by adding the following in any service provider's boot method:

```
 Session::extend('memcachedz2', function ($app) {
    return new CacheBasedSessionHandler(\Cache::driver('memcachedz2'), config(''session.lifetime'));
});
```

For your relatively simple use case approach 1 is probably easiest.